# Credential Management API (remove credential)

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

Is it possible with the browser´s credential api to remove a credential? I know that this is possibile in an Android app. Is it possible to do via javascript?

I was reading this tutorial https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api but they don´t have this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

There is no delete method, but if a stored credential is invalid, you can reuse the username and ask user to input a corrected password and call `store()` to update it.

Comment: Looks like it depends on client if and how credentials could be deleted from device. As of May 2023 it is possible to do it e.g. on latest iOS via settings->passwords; but it’s not possible to delete credentials individually from Windows Hello